# StaticInjector and NullInjector errors

Tags: typescript, angular6

I looked all over stackoverflow and some other sites as well and according to everyone, I should add an `HttpClientModule` import to the module file. Which I have done. Yet I still get the error.

**My module file**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GeneralamenComponent } from './generalamen/generalamen.component';
import { RoomamenComponent } from './roomamen/roomamen.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GeneralamenComponent,
    RoomamenComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule

  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**My service file**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

dataurl='http://localhost:4201/amenities';
getData(){
  return this.http.get(this.dataurl);
} }
```

**and my component file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Http,Response } from "@angular/http";
import AmenityInterface from '../AmenityInterface';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-generalamen',
  templateUrl: './generalamen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./generalamen.component.css']
})
export class GeneralamenComponent implements OnInit {
  datas: Array<AmenityInterface>;
  sdata:Object;
  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private http: Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
 this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data =>this.sdata = data
 )

  }

}
```

I'm at my wit's end. This one little thing has been bugging me for a long time now.

Here is the error. Do I need to add the html file too since the error is pointing out to the html file? [image]

Answer (score -1):

What I found, that 'Http' is deprecated and you should use 'HttpClient' instead. You can import it from '@angular/common/http'